# Keep getting "no match for 'operator<<' C++

Tags: c++

I'm writing a program to read text from a file and I need to print out the position that each of the numbers appear in the file. For example, the .txt file looks like this:

```
one
two one two
three three two one
```

and my output should look like:

```
one: 0, 2, 7
two: 1, 3, 6
three: 4, 5
```

Everything works fine until I try to display the map  of type string, list(int), then I get the whole ""no match for 'operator<<'" error.
Here is my code, any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string> 
#include <map>
#include <list>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream is("input.txt");
    if (is.fail())
    {
        cout << "File I/O error!" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    map<string, list<int> > m;
    string word;
    vector<string> v;
    list<int> l, x, y;
    while (is >> word)
    {
        v.push_back(word);
    }

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i)
    {
        if (v[i] == "one")
            l.push_back(i);
        else if (v[i] == "two")
            x.push_back(i);
        else if (v[i] == "three")
            y.push_back(i);
    }

    m["One"] = l;
    m["Two"] = x;
    m["Three"] = y;

    for (map<string, list<int> >::iterator i = m.begin(); i != m.end(); ++i)
        cout << (*i).first << ", " << (*i).second << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When asking about a compilation error: **1.** Post the complete & unedited error message (unless it's pages of nested template errors, in which case post the first few and the last few), **2.** Indicate on which source line *exactly* the error occurs. If that line is a complex expression, break it down into several statements, compile again and then post it here.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is when you try to output `(*i).second`. As `i` is of type `map<string, list<int> >::iterator` `(*i).second` is a `list<int>` and `c++` does not know how to output it.

You have two options - either overload `ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const list<int>& l)` or use an inner cycle to output the elements one by one. I personally recommend the second option as overloading the operator for such "popular" type may be dangerous.

Comment: Oh duh, should've seen that before. Thank you!

Comment: +1; Also, a third option would be to use `std::copy(i->second.begin(), i->second.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout));`

Comment: Personally, I have always considered it a **defect** that there was no automated print option for all Standard types. The most annoying issue is that `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, std::list<...> const&)` can only be picked up by ADL if **declared in `std`** which is forbidden by the Standard. As a result, the only way to get a decent solution for outputs is to... create a stream of your own. Oh joy...

Comment: @MatthieuM I didn't understand "The most annoying issue is that std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, std::list<...> const&) can only be picked up by ADL if declared in std which is forbidden by the Standard". Would you please explain?

Comment: @RonakPatel: ADL (Argument Dependent Lookup) will look-up functions in the namespaces of the arguments referenced. When you use `std::cout << myList` the arguments to `operator<<` are of type `std::ostream&` and `std::list<T, A> const&` so the *only* associated namespace is `std`. Unfortunately, it is strictly forbidden to add anything within `std` apart from specialization of existing templates (and that's only because a template should be specialized within the namespace it was declared in). Therefore, you are stuck.

Comment: @MatthieuM Thanks. Good explanation. Though standard forbids, we have "std::copy(example.begin(), example.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ", "));" this as an option as you mentioned below.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution:

```
// !!! DO NOT DO THIS AT HOME OR AT ALL !!!
namespace std {
    template <typename T, typename A>
    ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, list<T, A> const& l) {
        if (l.empty()) { return out << "[]"; }

        out << '[';

        bool first = true;
        for (auto const& t: l) {
            if (first) { first = false; } else { out << ", "; }
            out << t;
        }

        return out << ']';
    } // operator<<
} // namespace std
```

Unfortunately... it is strictly forbidden to do so (you are only allowed to specialize existing templates in the `std` namespace, not add any overload).

Therefore, the best standard compliant solution is to:

1. Declare a new stream of your own (which forwards everything to a `std::ostream&`)
2. Overload this operator for your new stream (in its namespace)
3. Only ever use this new stream afterward

Feel free to bitch at the clumsiness...

Example of custom stream [to get you started](http://ideone.com/mnB26y):

```
namespace project {
    class OStream {
    public:
        explicit OStream(std::ostream& out): _out(out) {}

        template <typename T>
        OStream& operator<<(T const& t) { print(*this, t); return *this; }

        template <typename T>
        void push(T const& t) { _out << t; }

    private:
        std::ostream& _out;
    }; // class OStream

    // Generic Operator (directly forwards to `std::ostream`)
    template <typename T>
    void print(OStream& out, T const& t) { out.push(t); }

    // STL Containers
    template <typename It>
    void print_range(OStream& out, It begin, It end) {
        if (begin == end) { out << "[]"; return; }

        out << '[' << *begin;

        for (++begin; begin != end; ++begin) { out << ", " << *begin; }

        out << ']';
    } // push_range

    template <typename T, typename A>
    void print(OStream& out, std::list<T, A> const& l) {
        print_range(out, l.begin(), l.end());
    } // operator<<
} // namespace project

// usage
int main() {
    std::list<int> example = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    project::OStream(std::cout) << example << "\n";
}
```

*Note: there are other solutions than creating a custom stream, such as copy pasting `std::copy(example.begin(), example.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ", "));` everywhere you need to print a list, but I am yet to meet another handy one.*