# no match for operator '<<' Can someone aid with void function error? [c++]

Tags: c++, function, return-value, void

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21155681/keep-getting-no-match-for-operator-c) post treats the same error, but the poster isn't have trouble with a void function.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28247474/why-does-it-literally-return-0-at-the-end-of-the-output) post concerns the "void" type of function, but the poster is advised to change the function type to "string", which does not help my case.

My code executes fine, except for a literal "0" at the end of the output. When I change the function type to "void", I am met with the above error.

I have been through the tutorial on this numerous times, and have searched thoroughly, yet have been unable to resolve this issue.

```
//my code
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int intervalcountdown (int a, int b) {
    for(a; a>0; a = a - b) {

        cout << a;

        if(a<=b) {

        break;
        }

        cout << ",";


    }
    cout << ".";
    return 0;
}


int main () {
    cout << intervalcountdown(20,3);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just don't print what you don't want.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void intervalcountdown (int a, int b) { // change return type to void
    for(; a>0; a = a - b) { // meaningless a is removed

        cout << a;

        if(a<=b) {

            break;
        }

        cout << ",";


    }
    cout << ".";
    // remove the return statement because the return type is now void
}


int main () {
    intervalcountdown(20,3); // remove extra printing
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That was rather simple. I had failed to remove the extra printing after changing the type to "void" and removing the "return 0;". For some reason I'm under the impression that "cout <<" is still necessary somewhere in the main () function. I'm still unsure as to why we don't use "cout <<" before calling the function.